# как отцентровать по вертикали <p>?

Tags: html, css

```css
.numbers {
  background:  rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5) url(backlogo.png) no-repeat ;
  filter:grayscale(100%);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  height: 501px;
  background-size: contain;
  text-align: center;
}
.numbers h3 {
  font-family: "Roboto Regular" sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}
.num {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="numbers">
  <h3>о нас в цифрах</h3>
  <div class="num">
    <div class="n1"><p>2907 <br>проведенных <br> мероприятий</p></div>
    <div class="n2"><p>11<br>лет на рынке</p></div>
    <div class="n3"><p>7000<br>человек<br>крупнейшее мероприятие</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.num {   
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
 }
```

Исправил свойство `flex-direction: row;` на `flex-direction: column;`